# can be spring-jcl libreary excluded?

Tags: spring

Here my current dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO]    \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
```

1. I don't quite figure out what's `org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.5:compile`. Could I exclude it from my project?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the javadoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.6/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html):

> Spring's variant of the Commons Logging API: with special support for Log4J 2, SLF4J and java.util.logging.
> This is a custom bridge along the lines of jcl-over-slf4j. You may exclude spring-jcl and switch to jcl-over-slf4j instead if you prefer the hard-bound SLF4J bridge. However, Spring's own bridge provides a better out-of-the-box experience when using Log4J 2 or java.util.logging, with no extra bridge jars necessary, and also easier setup of SLF4J with Logback (no JCL exclude, no JCL bridge).
>
> Log is equivalent to the original. However, LogFactory is a very different implementation which is minimized and optimized for Spring's purposes, detecting Log4J 2.x and SLF4J 1.7 in the framework classpath and falling back to java.util.logging. If you run into any issues with this implementation, consider excluding spring-jcl and switching to the standard commons-logging artifact or to jcl-over-slf4j.

So tl;dr: It is commons logging adapted for Spring and yes, you can exclude it. But you then may need to include a different library for logging.